# On select event for a cloned select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

What additional steps would I need to take in order to listen for the select2:select on a cloned select2?

I have tried `.clone(true)`, `$('.myclass').select2('destroy');` at the beginning of the click function, and refreshing DOM with `$('#table tbody').hide().show(0);`.

This appears to be the recommended way based on this GitHub issue.

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2522

```js
$('.myclass').select2();

$('.myclass').on('select2:select', function(e) {
 alert('foo');
});

$('#addRow').click(function() {
  $('#table tbody').append($('#table tbody tr:last').clone());
  $('#table tbody tr:nth-last-child(2) select').addClass('myclass');
  $('.myclass').select2();  
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="table">
 <thead></thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
      <select class="myclass">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select> 
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <select id="clone" class="hidden">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
       </select>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <button id="addRow">
    Add Row 
  </button>
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind events to dynamically added elements.

```js
$('.myclass').select2();

$(document).on('select2:select','.myclass', function(e) {
 alert('foo');
});

$('#addRow').click(function() {
  $('#table tbody').append($('#table tbody tr:last').clone());
  $('#table tbody tr:nth-last-child(2) select').addClass('myclass');
  $('.myclass').select2();  
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="table">
 <thead></thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
      <select class="myclass">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select> 
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <select id="clone" class="hidden">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
       </select>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <button id="addRow">
    Add Row 
  </button>
 </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the link and assist.